# How to do a series of series in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have two series: a and b,

```
a = Series(None, index=['a','b','c'])
b = Series('lol', index=['j','k','l'])
```

I would like to store b as one of the elements of a,

```
a['a'] = b
```

but I get

`ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

Is it possible to store a pandas series inside a pandas series? How can I do it? Thanks.

Comment: That is not what pandas is for.

Comment: Series is a one-dimensional labeled array (technically a subclass of ndarray) capable of holding any data type (integers, strings, floating point numbers, Python objects, etc.). i think it's not possible.

Comment: Thanks @ZagorulkinDmitry, but isn't the pandas series a python object as well? This is the reason of my confusion.

Comment: @ZagorulkinDmitry a Series is a python object :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can recast the `dtype` using the method [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
In [11]: a = a.astype(object)

In [12]: a['a'] = b

In [13]: a
Out[13]: 
a    [lol, lol, lol]
b                NaN
c                NaN
```

Alternatively (to using `astype`) when contructing `a` you can force the `dtype` to be object:

```
In [14]: a = Series(None, index=['a','b','c'], dtype=object)
```

The reason you are getting this error is because `float64`, doesn't allow a `Series` and similarly it doesn't allow strings - try to set `a['a'] = 'lol'` and you'll get a `ValueError`.

```
In [21]: a = Series(None, index=['a','b','c'])

In [22]: a.dtype
Out[22]: dtype('float64')
```

*You can read more about [type-casting in the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#copying).*

Comment: @ZagorulkinDmitry changed to use astype and link to the docs :)

Comment: Thank you Hayden! I'd buy you a pint if I were in London.